# how can i change jdbc connection in a test plan?

Tags: java, jmeter

i have a problem in jmeter jdbc connection configuration
i want to be able change dbURL, dbUsername and dbPassword AFTER running the plan
the problem is all of these properties loads ONCE
after a few research, i found this page:
https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jdbc/config/DataSourceElement.html#getUsername--

there are methods like setUsername and setPassword (exact thing that i want)
the problem is i am using below code in jsr233 controller (after the jdbc connection)

but in log viewer:

**No signature of method: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setUsername() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [test]**

what is the problem here?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;

Connection con = DataSourceElement.getConnection("A");
con.setUsername("test");
```

Comment: You can't, but why to change username?

Comment: i have a test plan that show the user a frame (JFrame) that gets mysql configuration (in JTextFields), then stores these parameters in vars (or props). the problem is when running this test plan for first time, the properties are null (because jdbc connection's properties only loads ONCE in loading the jmx file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to **predefine** one username per [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration).

> Creates a database connection (used by JDBC RequestSampler) from the supplied JDBC Connection settings.

You can have 2 configurations with different usernames and use each for different JDBC requests